# Navigate to a different route

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

is it possible to route like after an ajax call to another page?
So I know it is possible inside html with Angular2 TS but does it work with Dart and how?

```
@RouteConfig(const [ 
  const Route(path: '/search', name: 'Search', component: SearchComponent, useAsDefault: true), 
  const Route(path: '/create', name: 'Create', component: CreateComponent),   
  const Route(path: '/edit/:id', name: 'Edit', component: EditComponent) 
])
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what is the problem? Do you want to create a router link or navigate from code. What is the equivalent in TS that you know is working that you want to implement in Dart?

Comment: So actually I want to navigate to a different view.
In Angular there is the function 
`[routerLink]="['/Edit', { id: entry['articleId'] }]"` so, when I click a button it will navigate to the specified route. Now I want to implement something like this into my dart code to navigate automatic to another view.

Comment: What is automatic? When should it do this automatic and from where?

Comment: When an http request is called successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
MyComponent {
  Router _router;
  MyComponent(this._router); 

  makeHttpRequest() {
    if(success) {
      _router.navigate(['/Edit', { id: entry['articleId'] }]) 
    }
  }
}
```

depending on your concrete use case